# Mat-select value inside formarray not set when read from database

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular ( & stackblitz!), learning using Angular 6. I am trying out a mat-table (with multiple rows) which is having one column based on a mat-select. Everything works fine when i create a new row, the mat-option value selected is stored in a database.

But while getting the value from the database, the selected value is not shown on the web GUI.

I have looked at some of the earlier questions in this regard and am setting the mat-select object using the find option on the mat-option.

Basically, I am trying to store multiple phone records and have a drop down to select if the phone type is home/work phone number. This is modeled in a mat-table associated with a formArray.

Comment: We need some code snippet from you from helping you.!

Comment: I was able to workout my problem looking at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk-rp5jbf?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts .. the problem was the way i was setting the mat-select value in the formarray

Comment: I am seeing last 2 drop have select value like yes and no